# Can you create and modify Work Items in TFS 2010 without Team Explorer?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

We have a team that consists of a number of non-developers - for these non-developers to create and modify Work Items, would they need to have VS 2010 / Team Explorer installed on their machines? Or is it possible to create and modify Work Items through the project's SharePoint site or some other built-in means?

I've not yet installed a full test TFS 2010 instance, so I can't check it out myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create and edit work items from the sharepoint site for a team project in TFS 2010. but the users will still need a Client Access Licence (CAL) to do more than very basic work item management. The url will be something like `http://[tfsServer]/sites/[tfsCollection]/[tfsTeamproject]/Dashboards/ProjectDashboard_wss.aspx`. If you right click on the Team Project in Team Explorer and select "show project portal" then it will open a browser in the correct location.

I think the licence basically says that users can create and modify their own work items without a CAL. If they need to view work items created by other users, or allocate work items to other users, then a CAL is required.

Comment: If it is a work item that a user created, they can edit the work item including assigning it to a different user without requiring a CAL.

Answer (score 5):

You can also create or edit workitems using Team System Web Access portal which will be configured as part of TFS2010 Installation. You can access this portal using this URL: http://[TFSServer]:8080/tfs/web

You can also configure users to access the restricted version of this portal(Work Item Only View) which the users can connect without using CAL. In this version, the users can add or edit the workitems only created by them.

Comment: Out of curiousity, is the Team System Web Access Portal installed even if we go the SharePoint Integration route?

Comment: Team System Web Access will be installed on Application Tier and you can't install TFS2010 without Web Access Portal even you are going with SharePoint Integration.

Comment: If agile project management is a requirement, take a look at Urban Turtle (http://urbanturtle.com) this is a plug-in for Team Web Access. In January 2010, Microsoft review Urban Turtle and Brian Harry says '...awesome Scrum experience for TFS'. Read the full blog from Brian Harry here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/01/05/